# Putting the title attribute in image tag — Snapshot Theme from Woothemes

Tags: images, title

Does anybody know, how to insert the title used in the field "screenshot" and "large-image", in Snapshot Theme from Woothemes?

I´ve tried using 'the_title();', but I get the post title, not what I wrote in the "Title" field, in the additional fields "Snapshot Custom Settings".

Does anyone have used yet this theme? Does anyone know how to get that title?

The Theme website:
http://www.woothemes.com/products/snapshot/

My Customization:

http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/catalogo/

Thanks.

Comment: When talking about extensions please include link to it, so people don't have to spend time hunting it down themselves.

Comment: This link says something about, wordpress 3.5 not including image title, cause accessibility:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18984

But for those who might want to restore the image title, this plugin maybe a solution:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/restore-image-title/